# Error while process req with charset windows-1251

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a service written in node.js express.js
I get http request from another online service. This is header:

```
{ 
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1251',
  host: 'swift-language.info:3030',
  'content-length': '614',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive'
}
```

body-parser response with 415 error and express doesn't call my route.
I guess the problem is charset=windows-1251

Comment: Try using another body parser middleware, like [`express-busboy`](https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `body-parser` currently does not support non-UTF8 charsets. However [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) (and [other modules built upon it](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy) such as [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [express-busboy](https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy)) supports many charsets in addition to those built-in to node.